# How could I write this function the pythonic way?

Tags: python, string

I was asked to create a function to count the number of letters in sequence in a string, as I was being timed, this is what I came to:

```
def count_letter(inString):
    result = ''
    count = 0

    for l in xrange(0,len(inString)):
        count += 1
        if inString[l:l+1]!= inString[l+1:l+2]:
            result += str(count) + inString[l:l+1]
            count = 0
    return result

inp_string = "llasssoooaappeeoaaa"
result = "2l1a3s3o2a2p2e1o3a"
```

How can I improve this function to be more like the Python way?

Comment: It's a one-liner: `''.join('%d%s' % (len(list(g)), k) for k, g in itertools.groupby('llasssoooaappeeoaaa'))` => `'2l1a3s3o2a2p2e1o3a'`

Comment: Thank you @Aya!! That's exactly what I was looking for.